# Electron full screen - part of screen "missing" when on-screen keyboard is hidden on MS Surface

Tags: electron, chromium, pixelsense, on-screen-keyboard

We have an electron app which is executed full-screen on Microsoft Surface Pro (W10). Most of the time when the on-screen keyboard is hidden everything works well, the electron app takes again 100% of the height. However, sometimes a white area is left when the keyboard is hidden.

We were able to get this also in dev mode with the development tools open, see attached image. The html area is not full height, a white area is left below it. Can you help us to get rid of this white area, please?

[image: electron full-size with white area where keyboard was]

Browser Window Options:

```
//options to ensure kiosk behavior
const windowOptions = {
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    frame: false,
    fullscreen: false,
    resizable: false,
    focusable: true,
    movable: false,
    kiosk: true,
    webPreferences: {webSecurity: false, allowRunningInsecureContent: true}
};
```

Some additional version numbers:

- electron 4.2.12
- Windows 10